# Jordan type representation for sequences with bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis

We say that a sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers is of bounded variation iff 
$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_{n}-x_{n-1}|<\infty$
(where  $x_0:=0$).

Let $(x_n)$ be convergent to zero.

Do there exist monotonic convergent to zero sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ such that 
$x_n=a_n-b_n$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a sequence $(x_n)$ has a Jordan decomposition $x_n=a_n-b_n$, then

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_{k+1}-x_k|
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} |a_{k+1}-a_k|+|b_{k+1}-b_k|=|a_{n+1}-a_1|+|b_{n+1}-b_1|
$$

so $(x_n)$ has bounded variation.

Conversely, suppose the sequence $(x_n)$ has bounded variation. We may then 
define for all $n$,

$$
b_n=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} {\sf max}(0,x_{k+1}-x_k), \ a_n=b_n+x_n
$$

Then $|b_n| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} |x_{k+1}-x_k|$, so $(b_n)$ and
$(a_n)$ tend to zero.

Also, $(b_n)$ is nonincreasing by contruction.
Let $n$ be any integer. If $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$, then
$b_n=x_{n+1}-x_n+b_{n+1}$ and hence $a_n=a_{n+1}$. If, on the other hand,
$x_{n+1} < x_n$, then $b_n=b_{n+1}$ and hence $a_n > a_{n+1}$.

This shows that $(a_n)$ is nondecreasing, so we have constructed a Jordan
decomposition of $(x_n)$.